# Using Landsat MSS Collection 1

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, image

When I use Landsat MSS Collection 1 dataset in my roi, I can't get any images from Tier1, but Tier2 I can.

This is code from someone to count the number of image, each year.
When I switch to Tier2 ImageCollection, it has some images; When I delete `.filterBounds(roi)` it has some images too.

```
roi: Table users/INnoVation/DongYing // (Dong Ying in China)
var L2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LM02/C01/T1')
          .filterBounds(roi);
    
var years = ee.List.sequence(1972,1984);
var counts = years.map(function(year){
    var count = L2.filterDate(
        ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1), ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1),1,1)).size();
    return count;
    });
    
print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array.cat([counts]), 0, years)
     .setChartType('ColumnChart'));
```

Comment: Thank you, MrXsquared, for your edited!

Comment: can you provide your ROI, there can be tons of reasons why there is missing imanges in different landsat collections

Comment: roi is DongYing in China

Comment: please put it in your example so that you can provide a working example, you are more likely to get helpful answers.